# Как найти начало и конец сессии с slickstream

Tags: postgresql

В базе данных есть поля

```
user_id - идентификатор пользователя
site_id - идентификатор сайта
datetime - timestamp с временем клика на сайте
```

Slickstream сессии считают все данные клика с интервалом 30 мин 
Как я могу получить начало и конец с помощью SQL запросов 
чтобы в конце было
`user_id  site_id   session_start_time  session_end_time`

Comment: *все данные клика с интервалом 30 мин* Между первым и последним с в группе, или между каждой смежной парой в группе? И укажите точно СУБД, включая её версию.

Comment: БД PostgresSQL, нужны все данные с интервалом в 30 мин но нужно чтобы был по порядку

Comment: Пожалуйста, перечитайте мой комментарий ещё раз, и ответьте на вопрос из него, а не на тот, который Вы себе придумали. И укажите точно СУБД, **включая её версию**.